# Minio with TLS in OpenShift

Tags: laravel, kubernetes, openshift, minio

I have laravel application which is using minio as storage on OpenShift cluster. I'm trying to enable TLS(https). But anyway when I try to upload any images to minio I receive 403 Forbidden. It's successfully worked on http (without TLS).

I received TLS certificates from TLS provider(`private.pem`, `minio.crt` and `minio.ca-bundle` files). I concatenated `minio.crt` with `minio.ca-bundle` into `public.crt` and I created Openshift secret to handle https connection `oc create secret tls minio-tls --key private.pem --cert public.crt`. Also I renamed `minio.crt` into `public.crt` and placed it into folder (`/home/myuser/certs_minio/`) with `private.pem` and created Openshift configmap via this command `oc create configmap minio-certs --from-file=/home/myuser/certs_minio/`.  Can anyone help me?

Deployment:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minio    
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: sail2-minio
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sail2-minio
      - name: cert-volume
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: minio-certs
      - name: ca-certs-volume
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: openshift-service-ca.crt
      containers:
        - name: minio
          image: 'minio/minio:latest'
          args:
            - minio
            - server
            - /data/minio
            - '--certs-dir'
            - /.minio/certs
            - '--console-address'
            - ':8900'
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /minio/health/live
              port: 9000
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 20
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          env:
            - name: MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: XXXX
            - name: MINIO_ROOT_USER
              value: YYYY
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8900
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/minio
              name: sail2-minio
            - mountPath: /.minio/certs
              name: cert-volume
            - mountPath: /.minio/certs/CAs
              name: ca-certs-volume
```

Service

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  ports:
    - name: '9000'
      protocol: TCP
      port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
    - name: '8900'
      protocol: TCP
      port: 8900
      targetPort: 8900
  selector:
    app: minio
```

Ingress

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - minio.my-server.com
      secretName: minio-tls
  rules:
    - host: minio.my-server.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: minio
                port:
                  number: 9000
    - host: admin-minio.my-server.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: minio
                port:
                  number: 8900
```

**UPDATED**
Minio pods logs:

```
Warning: Default parity set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
MinIO Object Storage Server
Copyright: 2015-2022 MinIO, Inc.
License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
Version: RELEASE.2022-11-26T22-43-32Z (go1.19.3 linux/amd64)
Status: 1 Online, 0 Offline.
API: http://10.129.3.246:9000 http://127.0.0.1:9000
Console: http://10.129.3.246:8900 http://127.0.0.1:8900
Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
You are running an older version of MinIO released 5 days ago
Update: Run `mc admin update`
```

Minio route:

```
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
kind: Route
metadata:
  labels:
    app: minio
  name: minio-6fztw
spec:
  host: minio.my-server.com
  path: /
  port:
    targetPort: "9000"
  tls:
    certificate: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
    key: |
      -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
      -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
    termination: edge
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: minio
    weight: 100
  wildcardPolicy: None
```

CURL from ne of the cluster's pod:

```
curl minio.my-server.com -IL
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
content-length: 0
location: https://minio.my-server.com/
cache-control: no-cache

HTTP/2 400 
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 261
content-type: application/xml
server: MinIO
vary: Origin
date: Sat, 03 Dec 2022 00:01:39 GMT
set-cookie: 7d9780cddf96cdea5da436eeb53224e8=6143925dc959f1e842f292b797867446; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
```

**UPDATE 2**
Curl livenessprobe:

````
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
content-length: 0
location: https://minio.my-server.com/minio/health/live
cache-control: no-cache

HTTP/2 200 
accept-ranges: bytes
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: block-all-mixed-content
server: MinIO
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
vary: Origin
x-amz-request-id: 172D4EA033B0C73A
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
date: Sat, 03 Dec 2022 14:24:46 GMT
set-cookie: 7d9780cddf96cdea5da436eeb53224e8=2f4032867d91284df8fab35936da3c68; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=None
cache-control: private```
````

Comment: If Minio serves https, you want to use passthrough. This being OpenShift, I would know how to do this with a Route, I'm not certain what the Ingress object would look like. Though from your explanations, it is unclear what your error is (are those ingress controllers, or is it minio, answering with 403? can you query minio SDN addresses, from a node or another pod in your cluster?) Are you sure your liveness is OK (if https is enabled, would scheme http work here?). Have you checked pods logs, should tell you if it's listening in http or https, ... Please try to update your question

Comment: also note: in openshift context, dealing with certificates, we would usually use the openshift PKI managing SDN-internal certificates, while your "real" certificates would usually be configured on Routes exclusively. If you were to `oc annotate service minio service.beta.openshift.io/serving-cert-secret-name=oc-minio-tls`, this would create a Secret named `oc-minio-tls`, which you could use setting up https in Minio. Advantage of this would be that those server certificates would always be signed by an authority known to your ingress controllers. While you can keep real pub certs in Route.

Comment: @SYN I updated my question. Have I done it correctly (as you expected)?
Regarding  secret `oc-minio-tls` - should I use it instead of CA certificate (in my case: `openshift-service-ca.crt`)?

Comment: from your pod logs: we see minio listens in http, while the Route has a 'edge" tls termination (serves https to client, proxies connection using plain http). Which could be good enough in your case. Otherwise not sure what's that 400 ... Could you try to add `MINIO_SERVER_URL=minio.my-server.com` to environment variables in your minio server, maybe? Which version of openshift? HTTP2 was supported around 3.7/3.9. Can you curl liveness/readiness endpoints, eg: /minio/health/live ? or enable browser mode (`MINIO_BROWSER=on`) ?

Comment: When I set `MINIO_SERVER_URL=minio.my-server.com` the minio pods logs:
`ERROR Invalid MINIO_SERVER_URL value in environment variable: unexpected scheme found`
OS version `4.11.13`
I updated question to liveness curl

Comment: `MINIO_BROWSER=on` doesn't change anything.

Comment: If you can curl the liveness probe from outside your cluster, then what is your issue exactly? (while for the server_url: "unexpected scheme" should be a giveaway ...)

Comment: Your minio looks fine. Make sure bucket exists for your data, make sure laravel s3 user can write that bucket, ...

Comment: I can upload image to minio storage from laravel application. But laravel application can't GET it 403 Forbidden (I found this error in browser console).

Comment: I've found out that if I set minio bucket aas public the app can see this image. Do you know how to make the app show the images when bucket is private.

Comment: authenticate querying the bucket in your app. and make sure your app serves as a proxy when web client access those objects, as otherwise clients probably won't be able to authenticate directly themselves